# X11 forwarded program does not open in normal window

Tags: x11-forwarding

When I start gedit over a X11 forwarded SSH connection, it does not open in a normal window, as other applications do. Meaning it does not have the regular Microsoft Windows borders, making it very hard to move or resize. This happens when launching from my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS and not on my Ubuntu 15.04 VPS. I have tried on both Xming and CygwinX servers and it does the same on both. So I am assuming I don't have something installed correctly on my 16.04 VPS.
Attached are the two gedit windows. The one with the MS Windows borders is very easy to move and resize, the one without is not. Also, the good gedit(bottom image) is version 3.10.4 and the bad one(top image) is 3.18.3.

[image: bad gedit]

[image: good gedit]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the newer gedit is crap. The fix is remove the existing version of Gedit and replace it with the older version of Gedit as per this post http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/install-gedit-3-10-ubuntu-16-04-lts

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mc3man/older
sudo apt update && sudo apt install gedit gedit-plugins gedit-common
```